# How can i organize my ElasticSearch indexes?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, couchdb, elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch which i try to use to help a cool startup that needs a search engine.

My usecase is:

- Each user of the website has its personal space where he can create text documents
- Each user can share or not its content with limited people (friends)
- Each user can create public content
- Users may be from different countries
- Users may search on other stuff than posts (for exemple, search for another user)

Our data is hosted in CouchDB.

---

**1) Should i create one unique index or is it a good practice to create an index per user?**
I've read it's not a bad idea to put everything on the same index so you can search on many different things in the same time.
But i noticed ES provides the ability to search on multiple indexes so why not creating an index per user? 
Is it a problem because the maximum url size is limited and the index names are provided by the url or something else?

**2) Should i create one index or type per json document?**
I've mostly 2 different type of documents to index: posts and users.
If i want to be able to search on both of them in the same time, am i supposed:

- To create an index for posts and an index for users, and search both of them?
- To create one index and 2 different types, and search on both types of the same index?
  I don't really what will be the difference.

**3) Is it normal to have to create multiple rivers of the same type?**
For exemple, on the CouchDB river, which provide a "filter" attribute to receive only the documents matching your filter.
Thus if i want to index my posts and my users on 2 separate indexes or types, my first try will be create 2 CouchDB rivers which will both have a different filter and a different index and/or type.

Is it the way to do?

Comment: How many users do you anticipate, and how many machines do you plan to use?

Comment: i don't know :) it's a startup we'd like to have as many users and machines as possible :)

Comment: You mean as many users as possible on as few machine as possible, right? :-) Do you plan to do queries across users? How much data do you anticipate a typical user to have: Little enough to squeeze dozens or hundreds of users onto each machine, or will users be able to have enough data to use up all resources on one or more machines?

Comment: users can be very different... like twitter, there's you, and lady gage having 10000000 followers. I don't know, but some users will probably have a lot more data than others

Comment: Do you plan to do queries across users? That could be extremely inefficient if you have hundreds or thousands of users with separate indexes (or shards) on each machine.

Comment: Yes i plan to query across users. But finally i'm not going to create multiple indexes per user. There will be one index per type of objet, with a single type in it